# I am calling custom category adapter.How to set background for full screen in android when using custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have the layout for activity like this for creating listview but it is taking only background for listitems .i want background for full.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="50px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
    android:layout_marginRight="20px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
     >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30px" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>

   setListAdapter(new Categoryarrayadapter(this, c));
```

I am calling custom category adapter.How to set background for full screen.

Comment: set background to your layout in which you have listview so you can get easily..

Comment: Where's the listview object in the UI ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have extended ListActivity class and i was setting background image of adapter.I figured out the issue.I have to add following code in onCreate Method

```
    getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
```